# How to insert value into dynamic column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Columnnew varchar(50)
set @Columnnew ='NewColumn'
EXEC ('alter table dbo.Customers add '+ @Columnnew+' varchar(50)')

exec('insert into Customers ('+@Columnnew+')'+'values('+'jhj'+')')
```

I have Required Like This.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some apostrophes.

```
declare @Columnnew varchar(50)
set @Columnnew ='NewColumn'
EXEC ('alter table dbo.Customers add '+ @Columnnew+' varchar(50)')

exec('insert into Customers ('+@Columnnew+')'+'values('+'''jhj'''+')')
```